# Addition of 2 dataframes column to column by unique column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1

a b c 
1 2 3
2 4 5
3 6 7
```

and

```
df2
a b c
1 3 4
3 1 8
```

I want output to be

```
df3 
a b c
1 5 7
2 4 5
3 7 15
```

I tried `df1.add(df2,axis='c')` but not getting exact output.

referring this link http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html

Comment: and `a` is the "id" of the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `a` in both `df` with [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) and parameter `fill_value=0`.

Last if necessary convert values to `int` and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df1.set_index('a').add(df2.set_index('a'),fill_value=0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
   a  b   c
0  1  5   7
1  2  4   5
2  3  7  15
```

For removing not common rows omit `fill_value` and add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) if no `NaN` in both `DataFrames`

```
df = df1.set_index('a').add(df2.set_index('a')).dropna().astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
   a  b   c
0  1  5   7
1  3  7  15
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you very much @jezrael. 1 more thing I would like to add in the same question. What if when I want to drop rows which are not common. Here in above example I want to drop row number 2. where a ==2, which is not present in df2. How to do this ?

Comment: If in original data are no `NaN` use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and omit `fiil_value` parameter - `df1.set_index('a').add(df2.set_index('a')).dropna().reset_index()`

Comment: No there are no NA values as such. Total row is absent from data frame. But anyways I can drop such rows by comparing that with original data. Thanks once again for your prompt help.

Comment: Accepted.      @jezrael

Comment: @Ajayjadhav - Thank you very much, nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 5), (3, 6, 7)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>>
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([(1, 3, 4), (3, 1, 8)], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>>
>>> df1.index = df1['a']
>>> del df1['a']
>>>
>>> df2.index = df2['a']
>>> del df2['a']
>>>
>>> df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
     b     c
a
1  5.0   7.0
2  4.0   5.0
3  7.0  15.0
```

Or use `set_index()` method:

```
>>> df1.set_index('a').add(df2.set_index('a'), fill_value=0)
     b     c
a
1  5.0   7.0
2  4.0   5.0
3  7.0  15.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont want to drop that column, I mean I want to do the addition by that column. But yes your output is correct.